# MySQL indexes on id?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Should I put INDEX on staff_id & client_id

```
CREATE TABLE conversation (
    id INT(7) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    staff_id INT(7) UNSIGNED,
    client_id INT(7) UNSIGNED,
    summary TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (staff_id) REFERENCES staff(staff_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    INDEX( staff_id, client_id )
);
```

What about a many-to-many relationship table? it there any point in putting index there?

```
CREATE TABLE client_contact (
    id INT(7) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    client_id INT(7) UNSIGNED,
    contact_id INT(7) UNSIGNED,
    FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES contact(contact_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    UNIQUE ( client_id , contact_id )
);
```

Comment: You should put a foreign key on those columns to the tables they reference. Then they have the relation they need and an index will be created automatically

Comment: thank you so much, have added foreign key to my question... so by having those foreign key, i don't need INDEX( staff_id, client_id ) AND INDEX( client_id , contact_id )

Comment: For a many to many table, you would often want `unique (client_id,contact_id)`

Comment: Thank you so much ysth, the unique property together with INSERT IGNORE, really save me a lot of time when trying to deal with the multi relationship table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both of these tables are likely to be queried in both directions, you should have both versions of the composite indices. For the m-2-m table you should also drop the surrogate primary key. You have specified `INT(7)` everywhere, which probably means you want `MEDIUMINT` ([max unsigned 16,777,215](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html#:%7E:text=8388607-,16777215,-INT)), and [integer display width is deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html#:%7E:text=the%20ZEROFILL%20attribute%20is%20deprecated%20for%20numeric%20data%20types%2C%20as%20is%20the%20display%20width%20attribute%20for%20integer%20data%20types). I have also added `NOT NULL` to all the FKs, obviously you can change based on your needs:

```
CREATE TABLE conversation (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    staff_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    client_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    summary TEXT,
    INDEX ( staff_id, client_id ),
    INDEX ( client_id, staff_id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( staff_id ) REFERENCES staff ( staff_id ) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY ( client_id ) REFERENCES client ( client_id ) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE client_contact (
    client_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    contact_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( client_id , contact_id ),
    INDEX ( contact_id, client_id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( client_id ) REFERENCES client ( client_id ) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY ( contact_id ) REFERENCES contact ( contact_id ) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: thanks so much for the modification, while trying to make adjustment to the table, I need to save the conversation in case staff changes (Jennifer taking over Perrie's Job) , or contact changes (Jacqueline taking over Ben's Job), and when new staff (Jennifer)  takes over the job she can find out what conversation they had with the client (say Amazon)

Comment: should i use make a table call 'archive' to save the conversation incase staff or client is deleted? if so, how should I approach this puzzle?

Comment: i am trying to build a conversation database for a small company where the manager can monitor the conversation between staff & client..
in that case, maybe I am over designing? perhaps using the table you suggested is enough....

Comment: The point of my answer was to show you that the _"correct"_ way to index any m-2-m table is in both directions. And for junction tables, the surrogate key is just wasting space and an unnecessary overhead. Design questions are always subject to opinion, and as such, not suitable for SO. As for functional/business requirements, that is something you must pin down with your client.

Answer (score 0):

"Should I put INDEX on..." -- The answer always comes from the queries that use the table.  It is not possible to give you the correct/complete answer from just the `CREATE TABLE`.

However, since both of your tables smell like "many-to-many mapping tables", I will give you this answer:  [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

@user1191247 got `client_contact` correct.  But I can't tell about `conversation`.  If there can be only one staff:client pair, then I would argue against having `id`.